# The holiday doors from "The Nightmare Before Christmas"

Tags: the-nightmare-before-christmas

In *The Nightmare Before Christmas* Jack Skellington walks into a circle of trees to find the door to Christmas Town. But all of the doors correspond to holidays either Judaeo-Christian in origin or the US representation of a particular celebration. E.g. 4th of July /Independence celebration, Thanksgiving/ Harvest celebration.

While popular in the United States Halloween is celebrated in multiple countries worldwide. So where are the doors to the other holidays?

Is there any canonical evidence that indicates that there are other doors to these other holidays located somewhere in the forest?

Answer (score 2):

**There Are 7 Doors Visible On Screen**

- Valentine's Day - Heart.
- St. Patrick's Day - Four-leaf clover.
- Easter - Easter egg.
- Independence Day - Firecracker.
- Halloween - Jack-o'-lantern.
- Thanksgiving - Turkey.
- Christmas - Christmas tree.

The suggestion that these holidays all correspond primarily to US holidays, may be arguable.

Many countries celebrate their nation’s Independence Day, even if not every celebrated day is on July 4th. The “firecracker” symbol of the door might represent the Independence Day celebrations of Mexico, Cambodia, Bolivia, Australia, or France, just as easily as it may symbolize the US’ holiday.

Easter, Christmas, St.Patrick’s and Valentine’s Day are primarily Christian religious holidays, not US-centric, and are celebrated throughout the world. Valentine’s Day originated in 5th century Rome, while St. Patrick’s Day began being formally recognized in Ireland about four hundred years ago, predating US existence.

A Thanksgiving Day is also celebrated throughout the world, primarily giving thanks to bountiful fall harvest rather than celebrating colonial survival. Netherlands, Canada, Australia, Liberia, Saint Lucia, Switzerland, Granada, Brazil, and Rwanda are some of the diverse countries who celebrate a day of Thanksgiving.

The story is silent regarding whether additional doors beyond those shown onscreen exist. However, “the doors to other non-US holidays” are definitely inclusively represented to a degree by the those seven doors that are shown onscreen.

Comment: You’ve addressed an assumption in the question but does this really answer the question of where the (potentially) missing doors are?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Well, I didn’t want to assume a particular point of the question, but I do disagree to degree with question’s premise, and that disagreement might then result in mooting of the question or a part of it, as the same observation about Halloween actually applies to all of them to varying degrees. Minecraft pack includes a unique “Snowed-in Halloween Town” door in addition to Halloween Town, suggesting alternate universes of already-represented holidays might also exist in TNBC world too. 

Comment: FWIW you may want to link the wiki if you’re taking some information from there. Also with the addition of the last paragraph this is certainly better now as you’ve looped back to address the question.

Comment: That kinda answers my question. If we consider Minecraft as canon within the TNBC world than that alone gives proof of alternate universes and and in-theory alternate holiday doors that are not Judaeo-Christian in origin or the US representation of a particular celebration. I can edit my question to add that to the parameters.

Comment: Minecraft TNBC Pack: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/nightmare-christmas-mash-pack

Comment: Being from the UK, I'd have assumed the firework door represented Guy Fawkes and Bonfire Night; Independence Day wouldn't even occur to me. The Turkey Door having a Pilgrim-style hat as the step is definitely US only, though.

Comment: @Showsni not being from the UK, this is a legit question: Weren't the "pilgrim-style" hats things that the pilgrims wore to the new world because that's what they wore in the old world? I would find it hard to believe that they arrived in the new world, helped to claim it for King and Country, then promptly changed their style of head wear to note that they were now in a new country....

Comment: @FreeMan Yes. When the Mayflower arrived at Plymouth Rock in 1620 full of English citizens, America did not exist. American Thanksgiving has come to generally be a celebration of English proto-Americans trying to ensure the survival of a proto-American nation and the first American Thanksgiving in October 1621 was an English holiday celebrated by the English.

Comment: @FreeMan Side note - Buckles on hats is a myth that was likely created as a concept when people were making art about Pilgrims in the 19th century.

Comment: I think this is a stretch, unless you also posit some kind of perception filter that changes the doors based on the viewer's culture. I challenge you to find any country outside North America where a turkey and a hat could represent a Day of Thanksgiving or Harvest Festival (in the UK, turkey is associated with Christmas, but that's a different door). Saint Patrick's day is a national holiday in Ireland, and celebrated where there is an Irish diaspora, but to most of the world it is one of dozens in the Calendar of Saints.

Comment: Given that the holidays are in the US calendar order, use iconography that is specific to America (especially the turkey), and form a set of holidays that you'll only find as the primary set of holidays in America, I have to strongly disagree.

Comment: @OrangeDog Germany’s Thanksgiving, like America’s early on was celebrated with goose but has since been overtaken by Turkey. https://www.german-way.com/history-and-culture/holidays-and-celebrations/thanksgiving-in-germany/ “Over the past few decades, Truthahn (turkey) has become a popular dish, widely available in German-speaking countries.”

Comment: @SillybutTrue That's not actually what the article says. It says *as a celebratory meal*, Turkey is becoming more popular, but that *Ernstedank* is rarely an occasion for such. That sounds a lot like the UK, where goose was once a traditional Christmas dish, but turkey has now replaced it; neither would be associated with Harvest Festival. It goes on to say that "most Germans have only experienced Erntedankfest by seeing it on television". That doesn't sound like something that a German author would pick as one of seven doors to represent major festivals.

Comment: I always thought the fireworks represented New Year celebrations.

Comment: Reordering the holidays for that would destroy some of the arguments about observed American chronology, though, leaving things in total chaos. 